# Fixed length consecutive sub-sequences with largest minimal element

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a sequence n of numbers and a number
   K, 1 <= K <= n, we want to find a consecutive sub-sequence of length K 
   such that the smallest element in the sub-sequence is as large as possible.

I have been able to do it in O(n*log(k)) time by keeping current k elements in a binary tree and adding and deleting the next and the first element respectively while iterating through the array. How could I do it in O(n)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maintain a deque containing (in order) the elements in the window that are less than all subsequent elements in the window. At all times, the window minimum is at the front of the deque. To extend the window forward: pop the elements from the back of the deque that are greater than or equal to the new element. Push the new element onto the back. To retract the window forward: if the index of the element at the front of the deque is about to leave the window, delete it.

The amortized cost of maintaining the deque at each step is O(1). ([A real-time algorithm also is possible.](http://www.davideisenstat.com/reduq/))

Comment: Are you saying about priority queue?

Comment: @ZeshanKhanAlvi No, not a priority queue.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. What do you put exactly in your queue?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about this solution as its very interesting solutions for me?

Comment: @user3923424 If the window contains [3, 2, 5, 8, 6, 7], then the deque contains [2, 5, 6, 7], with the corresponding element indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in O(n) time by.
1) i=0
2) Find minimum from first K element and store the sequence start and end point.
3) Check if the element at K+i location is less than minimum
then start++,end++
4) goto step 3 if array not ended.
This algorithm is not written in the proper writing style but you may easily understand.

Comment: This stops working when the minimum element is the element at position i.

Comment: I could not understand whats the issue as its 100% working at me on page not code.

Comment: try on {1,2,3,4,5} with k = 2.

Comment: which programming language you are using i may send you a code.

Comment: for 1,2,3,4,5 and k=2 the min of 1,2 is 1.

Comment: Yes, for 1,2 min is 1 after that you add 3(it is bigger than minimum). Now how do you know the current minimum(as the original minimum has been removed)?

Comment: sorry the algorithm is not for your requirements. This is for the task if you want smallest number as minimized not maximized. I am trying to develop an algorithm for your required task.

Comment: We may use a linear sorting algorithm and then in sorted array the desired output is not an issue.

Comment: That will not be possible in O(n). It will take O(nk) or O(n*log(k)).

Comment: If we have a sorted array like 1,2,3,4,5 then the task could be done in constant time like if k=2 the result would be array from length-k to length.

Comment: Yes, but for larger k insertion will not be constant time.

Comment: what insertion i am saying that first sort then for sorted the logic is constant time like above comment.
If we have a sorted array like 1,2,3,4,5 then the task could be done in constant time like if k=2 the result would be array from length-k to length.